# Adverbial clause of concession in brackets?

Tags: clauses

I am doing a formal scientific paper writing and unsure of the following sentence:

> The representatives are visualized as the skeleton of the corridors (not necessarily the centerlines though).

As can be inferred, the adverbial clause of concession in the brackets is not important enough to make me bring it out. It just acts like a tip.

I wish to know whether this way of expressing concession is correct or not. Is there any way of improving it?

Comment: This sounds like proof-reading, and may be closed for that reason. If it isn't, I think you should explain in a little more detail what you are trying to say. For one thing, why is _skeleton_ singular when _representatives_ is plural? What, in any case, is a _skeleton of the corridors_? What are the _centerlines_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As somebody who uses too many brackets in my own writing to add mildly interesting but not essential points, I would move *though* to the start of the bracketed phrase and then replace the brackets with a comma, perhaps inserting a verb:

> The representatives are visualized as the skeleton of the corridors, though they are not necessarily the centerlines.